# Angular Observable using a counter

Tags: angular, angular5, observable

I am currently learning about asynchronous angular. I have some code below inside a function and inside a for each loop. I would like to find out the number of successful requests then produce a notification. I understand because of asynchronous the if statements are useless because numOfSuccessfulRequests with be 0. How would I produce a count then or provide a link to learning material, I am not sure what this issue is called.

I would like just on notification at the end after the for each loop, not on each call

```
 this.checkedItems.forEach(checkedItem => {
    let numOfSuccessfulRequests = 0
        apiCall(checkedItem.record.id, 'active').first().subscribe(
                  () => {
                    numOfSuccessfulRequests++
                  },
                  () => {
                    this._notification.error("A request failed")
                  }
              );
            });

        //numOfSuccessfulRequests won't have a value here, so the below code is useless

        if (numOfSuccessfulRequests === 1) {
              this._notification.success(`A request was successful`);
            } else if (numOfSuccessfulRequests > 1) {
              this._notification.success(`There were ${numOfSuccessfulRequests} successful requests`);
            }
```

Comment: At what moment do you want to produce notification?

Comment: move the if condition to inside subscribe function.

Comment: do you want the notification after all the successful execution of requests ?? or after the first successful request inside that loop?? can u please confirm.

Comment: There is a foreach wrapped around the outside, I want one notification after the last for each, my fault for not providing the for each in initial question

Comment: @theonestine Can u check my answer?. I think you don't need a counter variable

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with the sequence of `Asynchronous` call. You are executing success message the code before you get the response.

Just make the following change

declare at class level

```
public  numOfSuccessfulRequests = 0;
```

Change in api call

```
this.checkedItems.forEach((checkedItem, index) => {
    apiCall(checkedItem.record.id, 'active').first().subscribe(
              () => {
                this.numOfSuccessfulRequests++;

                //Display message for last API call
                if(this.checkedItems.length == index){
                   this.showSuccessMessage();
                }
              },
              () => {
                this._notification.error("A request failed");
              }
          );
        });
}
```

Create a function to show the message

```
showSuccessMessage(){

       if (this.numOfSuccessfulRequests === 1) {
          this._notification.success(`A request was successful`);
        } else if (numOfSuccessfulRequests > 1) {
          this._notification.success(`There were ${numOfSuccessfulRequests} successful requests`);
        }

}
```

Comment: I would only like one notification at the end and not on each call, is this possible

Comment: Yes, you can defined `numOfSuccessfulRequests` at  class level. Updated the answer.

Comment: @theonestine you can show the notification when the counter become 1 , So it will not send again

Comment: Still the showSuccessMessage function would be called after every successful api call rather than at the end? I just want showSuccessMessage to be called once

Comment: First of all you are in wrong assumption that if you keep this method at the end it will be called only once.

Comment: Even you keep it outside it will be called whenever api is called because both will be in same function and execution will be in sequence. First API will be called then show message will be called even it is at bottom.

Comment: My fault for not providing enough context, it is inside a for each, therefore on each loop through the showSuccessMethod will be called after the api call. I want one call at the end of the for each, but the counter has to count

Comment: my question was too ambiguous and not detailed enough, sorry

Comment: I got your point now. I have updated my answer with additional check for last call. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a notification after all the service execution, you can use  forkJoin in RxJS like below

> import { forkJoin, Observable } from "rxjs";

```
var services=[];
this.checkedItems.forEach(checkedItem => {

        services.push(apiCall(checkedItem.record.id, 'active'));
});
```

then you can run all the services together using forkJoin

```
forkJoin(services).subscribe((response)=>{

    //after all the successful requests 
    //response.forEach((eachRes)=>{console.log(eachRes)});
    this._notification.success(`A request was successful`);

});;
```

> Note : response will be an array based on the number of requests
>   response.